# Automating JiraPS-PowerShell Scripts with Task-Scheduler, Issue on Authentification

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks, jira, taskscheduler

I have created a script to bring missed Phonecalls to Jira. For this, I am using the JiraPS-Powershell Module.
The scripts work, if I am run them PowerShell ISE. But after creating a Task in Windows Task-Scheduler, the authentification fails.

JiraPS creates a Websession (Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestSession) and it seems that this Session cannot be accessed via Task-Scheduler.
Is there a way to solve this problem?
(If it is just a Task-Scheduler issue, I am happy to change to a different solution)#

Thank you!

Further information:

How I know that the Session is still existing?

```
PS C:\FreePBXToJira> Get-JiraSession

Username WebSession                                     
-------- ----------                                     
XX       Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestSession
```

I tried this before and after the scheduled Task and the Session is always available for me, but not for the Task-Scheduler

Answer (score 0):

At least I found a solution, which makes it possible to run the Script via Task-Scheduler. Instead of using the saved session, I create a new session every time. The drawback is, that I have to put my credentials in the script

```
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString "myPassword" -AsPlainText -Force
$mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("myUsername", $secpasswd)
New-JiraSession -Credential $mycreds
```